# Add a Validation To Custom Button on Standard Page layout

Tags: custom-button, validation, criteria

I have a custom button on a custom object, which redirected to a VF page via URL content source. But I only need to run it based on certain field value of my custom object. So without going to a VF page, can I run a validation to stop the process if the field value doesn't match?

Thanks,
Lahiru

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this through ajax request below is sample code which validate contact fields.

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/25.0/connection.js")}

if('{!Contact.Title}' == '' || '{!Contact.Phone}' == '' || '{!Contact.Email}' == ''}){
alert('Please populate Title. Email and Phone before procedding...');
}else{
window.location.href = <here you have to put the NEW Survey Page URL>;
}
```

Comment: Well the content source of the my button is URL. So how am I suppose to implement?

Comment: You can use execute JavaScript options.  Google for the same u can get many resources.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks For the Comments guys. I was able to do above validation using standard configurations, with record types. I simple create a new Record Type and assigned a Page Layout with NO custom button. And I have also implemented a WF Rule to set the new Record Type every time my criteria matches (regardless of Create/Edit). It works for me. Thanks for the help

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, vote up the answers that you find helpful. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/39620)

Comment: @martin this looks to me like the answers themselves didn't solve the users issue and this answer is how the user solved the issue.

Comment: @JennyB Yes you are correct